# Navigation in constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, prism

I have an app, where there is a chance that error might occur during whatever process.

User has to go through several steps, where one goes after the other (order of the form is strictly fixed).

What I have problem with is, that when in my constructor I see that some error has occurred, I want to immediately navigate to a special page, where I show all the error messages to the user.

Example: User clicked on the button Next, which should have taken him to a `Page2`, however during the constructor of that `Page2ViewModel`, the program has encountered several errors. Therefore rather than showing `Page2` to a user (he won't be able to work with that page at all), I want to immediately  navigate to a special page in the constructor.

Here is how my constructor looks like:

```
public DetailPageViewModel(IDataRepository DataRepository,
    IRegionManager regionManager,
    IMainCompanyRepository companyRepository,
    IBankTransactionsRepository bankTransactionsRepository,
    IBankRepository bankRepository,
    IRegionManager navigationService, 
    IErrorRepository errorRepository)
{
    _DataRepository = DataRepository;
    _regionManager = regionManager;
    _companyRepository = companyRepository;
    _bankTransactionsRepository = bankTransactionsRepository;
    _bankRepository = bankRepository;
    _navigationService = navigationService;
    _errorRepository = errorRepository;

    InitializeCommands();

    //Here is where error can occur
    InitializeValues();


    if (errorRepository.ContainsErrorMessage())
        _navigationService.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", App.Experiences.ErrorPage.ToString());
}
```

When I toggle a breakpoint in my `ErrorPageViewModel` I can clearly see, that constructor was initialized, however for unknown reason (to me) it still shows `Page2`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I am targeting WPF but I have already managed to solve the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to solve the issue by implementing `INavigationAware`, and moving my error logic from the constructor to here

```
    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        //check for error messages
        if (_errorRepository.ContainsErrorMessage())
            _navigationService.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", App.Experiences.ErrorPage.ToString());
    }
```